# RStudio blogdown generates empty "Posts" link on the top page

Tags: r, rstudio, hugo, blogdown

I tried to make a website with RStudio blogdown through [this document](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/).

I expected the following list:

> ### 2017
>
> - Blog post 2
> - Blog post 1

But I got this:

> ### 2017
>
> - **Posts** (link to /posts/)
> - Blog post 2
> - Blog post 1

I got the same issue even when I didn't edit config or content from the document.

I don't know why the empty "Posts" item always appears on the top of blog post list.
How could I delete the item?

[image]

The config file `config.toml` (remain the defaults):

```
baseurl = "/"
relativeurls = true
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "A Hugo website"
theme = "hugo-lithium-theme"
googleAnalytics = ""
disqusShortname = ""
ignoreFiles = ["\\.Rmd$", "_files$", "_cache$"]

[permalinks]
    post = "/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"

[[menu.main]]
    name = "About"
    url = "/about/"
[[menu.main]]
    name = "GitHub"
    url = "https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown"
[[menu.main]]
    name = "Twitter"
    url = "https://twitter.com/rstudio"

[params]
    description = "A website built through Hugo and blogdown."

    # options for highlight.js (version, additional languages, and theme)
    highlightjsVersion = "9.9.0"
    highlightjsLang = ["r", "yaml"]
    highlightjsTheme = "github"

    [params.logo]
    url = "logo.png"
    width = 50
    height = 50
    alt = "Logo"
```

`devtools::session_info('blogdown')`

```
Session info --------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
 system   x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.0.136)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  ja_JP.UTF-8                 
 tz       Asia/Tokyo                  
 date     2017-04-06                  

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source                           
 backports   1.0.5   2017-01-18 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                   
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                   
 bitops      1.0-6   2013-08-17 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                   
 blogdown    0.0.25  2017-04-05 Github (rstudio/blogdown@1c10d16)
 bookdown    0.3.16  2017-04-05 Github (rstudio/bookdown@9ea8ffa)
 caTools     1.17.1  2014-09-10 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                   
 digest      0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                   
 evaluate    0.10    2016-10-11 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                   
 highr       0.6     2016-05-09 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                   
 htmltools   0.3.5   2016-03-21 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                   
 httpuv      1.3.3   2015-08-04 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                   
 jsonlite    1.3     2017-02-28 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                   
 knitr       1.15.18 2017-04-05 Github (yihui/knitr@2cd8ca3)     
 magrittr    1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                   
 markdown    0.7.7   2015-04-22 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                   
 mime        0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                   
 Rcpp        0.12.10 2017-03-19 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                   
 rmarkdown   1.4     2017-03-24 cran (@1.4)                      
 rprojroot   1.2     2017-01-16 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                   
 servr       0.5     2016-12-10 cran (@0.5)                      
 stringi     1.1.3   2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                   
 stringr     1.2.0   2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                   
 yaml        2.1.14  2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
```

Comment: This might be better suited for either SuperUser or the Server Admin site.

Comment: Please provide your `devtools::session_info('blogdown')` and Hugo version (`blogdown::hugo_version()`). I also recommend you to `devtools::install_github('rstudio/blogdown'); blogdown::install_hugo(force = TRUE)`.

Comment: I put `devtools::session_info('blogdown')` above. `blogdown::hugo_version()` is 0.19. I force installed hugo, but nothing changed.

Comment: This is a valid question. The OP didn't provide instructions on how to reproduce the problem, but since I'm the author of the R package blogdown, I know how and today I discovered that I was able to reproduce it. I'll investigate the issue and post an answer.

Comment: While waiting for this post to be re-opened, I have figured out the problem. There was a change in Hugo 0.19 that introduced this issue. I have provided [a fix](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme/commit/b346c203198f75d061b630135507d3a5acbe6144) in my hugo-lithium-theme. Basically you need to delete your theme, and use `blogdown::install_theme('yihui/hugo-lithium-theme')` to reinstall the theme. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thank you! The problem was fixed after I reinstall the theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a change in Hugo 0.19 that introduced this issue. I have provided [a fix](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme/commit/459df371404cc9627bcd697e0f435928a45540c3) in my hugo-lithium-theme. Basically you need to delete your theme, and reinstall it:

```
blogdown::install_theme('yihui/hugo-lithium-theme')
```

Comment: Come from your post, dailao!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I would try to change something on a similar location of this [file](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme/blob/master/exampleSite/config.toml), you can find on your project, try to delete it and see if it works!

I hope it works!

Comment: Thanks.
My config file is here. I edited a little.

https://github.com/sugi2000/visdom/blob/master/blogdown/config.toml

Comment: I didn't solve the problem yet. The 'Posts' item still sticks on the top of the post list. My config file doesn't include words like 'posts'.

Comment: Where did you put the "test" after "Posts"? Did you try to delete the folder of the theme?

Comment: Could you look at [my site](https://sugi2000.github.io/visdom/)?
I made only two posts, 'Test' and 'Test post 2', but empty 'Posts' item always appears on top.

Comment: And the source dir is [here](https://github.com/sugi2000/visdom/tree/master/blogdown).

Comment: Well, my best help now is saying that I think the solution can be in this [file](https://github.com/sugi2000/visdom/blob/master/blogdown/themes/hugo-lithium-theme/layouts/_default/list.html), maybe some check on if (this code `{{ if and .IsHome .Content }}` could be different? `{{ if  .IsHome and .Content }}`, by the way it's my best

Comment: I didn't touch files in theme dir. I got an error when I replaced 'and'.
`Error while rendering "page ": template: theme/_default/list.html:5:8: executing "theme/_default/list.html" at <.IsHome>: wrong number of args for IsHome: want 0 got 2`.
I couldn't find the cause. I'll try to make the site over from scratch.

Comment: I might have seen this problem before. I don't remember exactly, but you may try to update blogdown and Hugo first (instructions given in my comment under your question).